# Cassandra - Recommended approach to storing user display name on the post (and what happens if display name changes)

Tags: php, nosql, cassandra

I have a website where people can post messages and I store them in this form:

```
post_id : {user_display_name, title, body}
```

for example:

```
234567 : {
    user_display_name : "John Doe",
    title : "Title here now",
    body : "Body of the post here"
}
```

My problem now is, what happens if `John Doe` decides he's gonna change his name to `John Lorem`? In a relational database, I would just have a user id that points to user information so that if he changes his name, changes will reflect everywhere.

How can I achieve this in a NoSQL database?

Because I don't think it is practical to lookup `John Doe` in the whole keyspace and change it to `John Lorem`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you maintain a Column Family for post's by user you should pull all the post's for that user and change their display name.

Similarly in RDBMS without index (aka relation ship) you will end up accessing full table to change display name.

However, you can write Map-Reduce to identify post for user and change their display names and for future you can maintain a column_family with.

```
ROW -> USERID (or) USERID_YYYYMM (to avoid hot-spots)
COLUMN Name -> Reverse(TimeStamp):PostId
```

This column family will also help you quickly fetch latest Postid's by userid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is this not too resource intensive? Because that firstname-lastname combination could be in a lot of tables since this is a non-relational database.

Comment: If you give more details like column family's and expected queries then someone can help you in better way here.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find it sometimes still makes sense to store data that may change using IDs as you would in a relational model.  Considering the extra lookup to get the name for ID is really cheap, this tends to be more reasonable than running through your entire CF to make the change.